# Cannot mark text when inserting into buffer within post-command-hook

Tags: region, mark

When I add this post-command-hook:

```
(defun insert-into-a-buffer ()
  (with-current-buffer
      (get-buffer-create "some-buffer")
    (insert "a")))

(add-hook 'post-command-hook 'insert-into-a-buffer :local)
```

I cannot mark text regions.  This appears to be because some of the commands I use in my post-command-hook function internally set the `deactivate-mark` to `t`, which causes the `(deactivate-mark)` function to be run after I run my post-command-hook function.

I have tried multiple different methods of getting at the stack trace to show me how and why the `(deactivate-mark)` function is called, but no method has given me a stack trace that includes its caller, so it appears that `(deactivate-mark)` is the top-level function that is being run.  This corroborates with the answer to [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19275/keep-region-activated-upon-completion-of-my-command), which explains that the `deactivate-mark` variable can be set to `t` during a command in order for mark to be deactivate after the command.

Exact steps to reproduce:

- Run `emacs -Q`
- (optional) Press `C-SPC` to set mark.  Move point around.  Observe that the region between point and mark is visually highlighted.
- Enter the above code, and evaluate it.
- Press `C-SPC` to set mark.  Move point around.  Region between point and mark is not highlighted.

Expected behavior: Region between point and mark is visually highlighted, even after evaluating those 2 lines of elisp.  Actual behavior: Region between point and mark is not highlighted.

---

The answer linked says that as a possible fix, `(setq deactivate-mark nil)` can be placed at the end of your command to prevent mark from being deactivated.  However, some commands such as `kill-region` intentionally and quite correctly set it to `t`.  If I set `(setq deactivate-mark nil)` at the end of my command, I  interfere with those commands' correctly deactivating mark once they are run.

That answer also says `C-h v deactivate-mark` says `Automatically becomes buffer-local when set` regarding the `deactivate-mark` variable, but when I run `C-h v deactivate-mark`, that is not mentioned.  Has this been changed?  I guess I'll need to do a git bisect...

Comment: The question is unclear. What do you mean by "I cannot mark text regions"? Be specific. Provide a recipe to repro what you see, starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file). Say what you see at each step, and what you expected to see instead.

Comment: @Drew See edits - added exact steps to reproduce the behavior.

Comment: Thanks. But in that case it appears to be a [duplicate](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/19275/105) question. I retracted my vote to close because it was unclear, but now it should be closed because it is a duplicate. (I can't vote for that now, myself, but others can.)

Comment: @Drew This question isn't quite a duplicate of that one -- see edits.  If I simply put `(setq deactivate-mark nil)` at the end of my function, it interferes with mark's correctly being deactivated when I manually insert text or `C-w` (kill-region).  Your answer to that question mentions that `deactivate-mark` becomes buffer-local when set, but I do not see that in my `C-h v deactivate-mark` so I suppose that was changed between 2016 and today.  If it were still buffer-local, I don't think I would be having a problem at all, since my post-command-hook edits a different buffer.

Comment: "changed between 2016 and today" - I see the usual `Automatically becomes buffer-local when set.` in the doc, using the latest Emacs version from emacs-26 and master compiled in the last few days.

Comment: @Drew While the two questions are related, they aren't quite duplicates. Wrapping around a specific command and dealing with a post-command hook is evidently different enough that the same solution doesn't always work for both.

Comment: Note that `(add-hook 'post-command-hook 'insert-into-a-buffer :local)` makes the APPEND argument non-nil, *not* the LOCAL argument.

Comment: @npostavs @Drew Updated to latest version of emacs and now `deactivate-mark` is buffer-local for me too.  Sorry, I was on version 24 before!  It was obviously incorrect to assume that Debian Stretch would come with a recent version of emacs.  Because deactivate-mark is buffer-local now, the problem no longer happens, with no changes at all to the code I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What didn't work in [Keep region activated upon completion of my command](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19275/keep-region-activated-upon-completion-of-my-command) does seem to work here. You want to ignore the changes that the code you're running might make to `deactivate-mark`. So arrange for these changes to affect only a local variable that will no longer exist when your hook returns.

```
(defun insert-into-a-buffer ()
  (let (deactivate-mark)
    (with-current-buffer
        (get-buffer-create "some-buffer")
      (insert "a"))))
```

Comment: For the record this did work, however I also updated to the latest version of emacs where `deactivate-mark` is now a buffer-local variable, so this solution is no longer needed!