# How to insert text and activate the mark in the same function

Tags: mark, insert

I am trying to write a function where I insert some text, and then activate the mark at the end of the function. I have several use-cases where I would like to use this.

I cannot figure out how do make it work. I have the following expression which I am using to test the behavior:

```
(progn
  (set-mark-command nil)
  (save-excursion
    (insert "hi"))
  (forward-line 2)
  (activate-mark))
```

Evaluating this expression does not activate the mark; however, if I comment out the save-excursion part which inserts some text, the mark is activated. Why isn't the mark being activated, and what can I do to make the expression work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

My question is a duplicate of [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/40762/cannot-mark-text-when-inserting-into-buffer-within-post-command-hook) and [this one](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19275/keep-region-activated-upon-completion-of-my-command).

Quick recap:
From the answers in those threads, it seems certain commands will deactivate the mark. `Insert` appears to be such a command.

We can fix this issue in two ways:

1. Change the first line

```
- (progn 
+ (let (deactivate-mark)
    (set-mark-command nil)
    (save-excursion
      (insert "hi"))
    (forward-line 2)
    (activate-mark))
```

This sets the variable `deactivate-mark` to `nil`. This was the first time I had seen a `let` with a variable without assigning it a value. You can read more about this [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Local-Variables.html).

2. Unset the variable `deactivate-mark` at the end of our function

```
 (progn 
   (set-mark-command nil)
   (save-excursion
     (insert "hi"))
   (forward-line 2)
   (activate-mark)
+  (setq deactivate-mark nil))
```