# How to prevent deactivating the region after a command?

Tags: region

When a function is called on a region, I want a visual indication of affected area (a blink for ex.). Say, I've written a function upcasing previous word, and after evaluation I immediately get the result (and that's good) but I also want region highlighted for a sec. How could it be implemented?

Also I even can't get the region remain highlighted after the evaluation. `(setq mark-active t)` doesn't seem to work at all. Mark is forced to deactivate after interactive function or what?

```
(defun upcase-previous-WORD ()
  (interactive)
  (set-mark (point))
  (forward-whitespace -1)
  (call-interactively
     'upcase-region)
  (exchange-point-and-mark)
  (setq mark-active t)))
```

Comment: I don't know if this could be of any help, but you could have a look at how library [volatile-highlights](https://github.com/k-talo/volatile-highlights.el) adds visual highlights to some operations such as `yank` and `delete-region` and see if some of the code there can help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep region activated upon completion of my command](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/19275/keep-region-activated-upon-completion-of-my-command)

Answer (score 1):

[ I'll answer the second question.  ]

Yes, Emacs resets `mark-active` to nil automatically after executing a command which modified the buffer (or more specifically, after executing a command which set `deactivate-mark` to a non-nil value).  To prevent that you can use `(setq deactivate-mark nil)` in your function (after performing the buffer modification).